# iphone paint on top / overlay with event pass through

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I would like to be able to paint on top of my subviews, or in other words: have an overlay that does not block the events. So far I discovered:
- any instructions in drawRect are painted below subviews, 
- putting a transparent UIView on top blocks events.

Is there another trick I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Use a transparent UIView on top, and in IB uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" for that view, then input events will go down to your controls beneath it.

Or, in code do:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] init...];
overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you want to forward the hitTest events. Add the code below to your project, add a UIImageView to your interface, set its Class to ClickThroughImageView and connect the "onTopOf" outlet to whatever UIView is below the image.

The ClickThroughImageView.h file:

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface ClickThroughImageView : UIImageView 
    {
        IBOutlet UIView *onTopOf;     
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *onTopOf;

    @end
```

The ClickThroughImageView.m file

```
#import "ClickThroughImageView.h"


@implementation ClickThroughImageView : UIImageView
@synthesize onTopOf;


- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return [onTopOf hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```